# static files - asp.net web api core 2.1 authentication scheme Bearer

Tags: identityserver4, static-files, bearer-token, asp.net-core-2.1

How can I avoid static files from being authenticated?

For every request on a static file (images, .js, .css, etc) a message is logged with "AuthenticationScheme: "Bearer" was not authenticated.". Although the message is just logged when the configuration is set to debug, the resources wasted on this are just unnecessary.

Everything works fine, I just want to avoid checking authentication on these requests. Is there a way to disabled this? I've tried several variations on where the authentication is set on the Configure method, but nothing worked.

This is my current configuration:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
        app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");                
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        app.UseCors("default");
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });    

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {                
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });            

        DataAccessLayer.WebHelpers.Configure(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it by branching the request pipeline, applying authorization to '/api' path only:

```
        //app.UseAuthentication();
        app.MapWhen(x => x.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"), builder =>
        {
            builder.UseAuthentication();
            builder.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();     
        });

        app.MapWhen(x => !x.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"), builder =>
        {
            builder.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
            builder.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        });
```